# Validation in java Error log in register

Tags: java, validation, user-interface, authentication, passwords

I am trying to set the validation of Confirm password and all the textfield must have value in it. IM just a beginner sir im practicing to build a log in and register program.

SORRY for the english im not really great in speaking english.

My problem is my code is not running FINE. it keeps telling "fill the spaces"

```
String username = usernamefield.getText();
String password = passwordfield.getText();
String cpassword = cpasswordfield.getText();
if ((username != null) || (password != null) || (cpassword != null)) {
    if (password == cpassword) {
        db.insertData(username, password);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data has been entered");
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Fill the spaces");
    }
}
else if (password != cpassword) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Mismatch");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if((username != null) || (password != null) || (cpassword != null) ){
if(password.equals(cpassword)){
    db.insertData(username, password);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data has been entered");
}else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Mismatch");
}


 } else {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Fill the spaces");
}
```

Try this code. You should use equals() instead of == for string comparison

Comment: cannot find symbol :( i dont know the use of equles yet

Comment: Sorry for that. I made a spelling mistake. use equals() , :)